# Randomly generated hexadecimal number in C#

Tags: c#, random, hex

How can I generate a random hexadecimal number with a length of my choice using C#?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
static Random random = new Random();
public static string GetRandomHexNumber(int digits)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[digits / 2];
    random.NextBytes(buffer);
    string result = String.Concat(buffer.Select(x => x.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
    if (digits % 2 == 0)
        return result;
    return result + random.Next(16).ToString("X");
}
```

Answer (score 23):

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.Next();
string hexString = num.ToString("X");
```

`random.Next()` takes arguments that let you specify a min and a max value, so that's how you would control the length.

Comment: It'll work only if `length <= 8` as `int.MaxValue` fits in 8 hex digits.

Comment: If he really does want the hex string to be of a length of his choice, you will need code that calculates the minimum number with hex length 'x' and maximum with length 'x'.

Comment: Yep.  I left that out on purpose, but you would basically just have to do a conversion on 0xF? ('scuse my regular expression) to find whatever integer matched your desired length.

Comment: `int num = random.Next(1000, 5000);` - you can set any number of Range `random.Next(1000, 5000);` here random number generate between 1000 to 5000

Answer (score 10):

Depends on how random you want it, but here are 3 alternatives:

1. I usually just use Guid.NewGuid and pick a portion of it (dep. on how large number I want).
2. System.Random (see other replies) is good if you just want 'random enough'.
3. System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider

Comment: Slicing up a GUID seems like a real bad idea to me. They're only unique taken as a whole. Many bits of a GUID certainly don't qualify as random.

Comment: @spender is correct, for instance many GUIDs contain the MAC address of the PC generating them.

Comment: Eh, no, the mac-address based guids were retired back in 2000-ish as they were considered a potential security issue. GUIDs are now generated by a random number generator (122 bits random, 6 bits non-random). Either way, using a 32 (or more) bit slice of a guid gives a more random number than System.Random.

That is - unless you call UuidCreateSequential which was added for backwards compatibility in case anyone want old style guids, but that is a different story.

Comment: Yes. See the documentation for System.Random at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I needed something similar to Python's [`secrets.token_hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_hex) function.

If you need random bytes that are cryptographically secure, you can use [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider) in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace, like so:

```
using var csprng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
var bytes = new byte[16];

csprng.GetNonZeroBytes(bytes); // or csprng.GetBytes(…)
```

To convert the byte array to a hexadecimal string, using LINQ seems like the most readable option:

```
string.Join("", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))); // or "X2" for upper case
```

The output might look like this:

```
7fb70c709a5eed32d37ed5771f09c0fe
```

Answer (score 4):

.... with LINQ

```
private static readonly Random _RND = new Random();

public static string GenerateHexString(int digits) {
    return string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, digits).Select(_ => _RND.Next(16).ToString("X")));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be a cryptographically secure you should use RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

```
public static string BuildSecureHexString(int hexCharacters)
{
    var byteArray = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling(hexCharacters / 2.0)];
    using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(byteArray);
    }
    return String.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(byteArray, x => x.ToString("X2")));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that would return a 256-bit hex string (8x8=256):

```
private static string RandomHexString()
{
    // 64 character precision or 256-bits
    Random rdm = new Random();
    string hexValue = string.Empty;
    int num;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        num = rdm.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
        hexValue += num.ToString("X8");
    }

    return hexValue;
}
```

Comment: the random hex string will not be unique if called several times in order.

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 8, which releases Nov. 14-16, 2023, you can use the new method from `System.Security.Cryptography`:

```
RandomNumberGenerator.GetHexString(int stringLength, bool lowercase = false);
```

Microsoft states that:

> Creates a string filled with cryptographically random hexadecimal characters.

This should be the best method moving forward.

Answer (score -1):

Create an n character (~n/2 byte), random string of hex:

```
var randBytes = new byte[n/2 + n%2>0?1:0];
new Random().NextBytes(randBytes);
var hex = BitConverter.ToString(randBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty).Substring(0,n);
```

Have you considered Base64 strings? Depending on your application, they can often more useful. They're guaranteed to be ASCII and provide ~4/3 characters per input byte. To create an n character string:

```
var randBytes = new byte[(n/4 + n%4>0?1:0)*3];
new Random().NextBytes(randBytes);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(randBytes).Substring(0,n);
```

Obviously, you can omit the .Substring(0,n) if your application does not require either an odd number of hex characters or a Base64 that is not a multiple of 4 characters.

Feel free to extend the examples by making Random() static, as other posters have suggested.